# how to develop iOS camera view like bank deposit check

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-camera

Could anybody tell me how I can develop the feature like deposit checks feature in Wells Fargo bank iOS app ? To implement it, should I customize the default UIImagePickerController or AVCaptureSession or something else? the camera function I want looks like the attached screenshot : [Wells Fargo iOS app - deposit check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9IzK.jpg)

I don't need the image processing function ,just want to know how to customize the camera view like this.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a website to have other people do your work for you. Have you done any research on how this could be done? Have you tried to do it by yourself? If you have, show us your work and we can help you figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your comment. And I did do research by myself on this. As what I mentioned in the question, there are two possible methods : one is customizing the UImagePickerController, by adding an overlay view on top of it, but seems like we cannot make it landscape orientation, and I didn't find useful resources to teach me how to draw the frame on it; Second is using the AVCaptureSession, which is taking a video stream, but all I need is just taking a single image, then I don't think it's an option.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the functionality you need.

You can customize the UIImagePickerController interface. In the image capture interface, you can hide the standard controls by setting shows- CameraControls to false, replacing them with your own overlay view, which you supply as the value of the cameraOverlayView. If it is all you need UIPickerImagePickerController might be all you need.

But you should probably consider getting rid of UIImagePickerController altogether and designing your own image capture interface from scratch, based around AV Foundation and AVCaptureSession. You get no help with interface, but you get vastly more detailed control than UIImagePickerController can give you. For example, for stills, you can control focus and exposure directly and independently and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll read more details of AVFoundation && AVCaptureSession. This is the answer that I want, telling me the framework that can work on it.